# HTTP JSON and REST

Tags: json, web-services, rest, http

Does JSON messages sent over HTTP in response to a URL request make it REST-compliant?
I believe it is not.
But I am not sure  on the detailed reason.
If i have a well-organized website,which responds to URL requests with json representation payload - what does it need to do further to comply with RESTful or JAX-RS?
A simple concise explanation will be much appreciated

Comment: As far as I know, there is no official standard for RESTful services. Personally I find strict by-the-book REST to be obnoxious, since the real world doesn't always correspond to the GET/PUT/POST/DELETE rules that REST infers. In my opinion, it's all about what works best for you.

Comment: You should use a standard JSON hypermedia format (e.g. JSON-LD) and add hyperlinks to the response. Ofc. you have to follow the HTTP standard as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no restriction regarding the payload of messages in REST and using JSON format in HTTP responses isn't enough to make a service RESTful.

To make short (since it's what you asked for ;-)), what is really important in REST is to respect the HTTP operations (GET, POST, ...) are designed for, the concept of resources and their states (idempotence, ...), leverages headers and status codes, ...

The following link could give you hints about the way to implement a RESTful service / Web API:

- Designing a Web API - https://templth.wordpress.com/2014/12/15/designing-a-web-api/

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Answer (score 0):

JSON is a payload and does not play any role in making your Webservice REST-complaint.

Payload could be XML, CSV, plain text etc etc.

The Webservice will be REST-Complaint when it's following REST protocol (set of rules, not network protocol).

There are up to 4 levels where you can make your REST webservice complaint to.

One of the very basic rules to understand is that - `Your Request must not be RPC` i.e. you *MUST* not perform any action using a Payload (Typical SOAP) or URL tunnelling e.g. `http://www.example.com/product?id=1234&action=delete`

In RESTful world you would define one top level *URI* for the above. e.g. `http://www.example.com/product`

and then you will call various URLs to perform other actions.

*Such as:*

1. *POST - create Data*

   `http://www.example.com/product`

   `Body{ here your payload will describe the Product.}`

   Assuming you rely on server gennerated product id then return type could be Product Id. Which is again should be set as LOCATION parameter of the return header.
2. PUT - Update Data

   `http://www.example.com/product/1234`

   `Body{ here your payload will contain the Product details to change.}`
3. GET - Get Data

   `http://www.example.com/product/1234`
4. DELETE - Delete Data

   `http://www.example.com/product/1234`